# Restore listener after Activity recreate (pass photo to a custom view returning from camera)

Tags: android, android-camera, listener

I have an activity with a fragment. Inside a fragment I have 2 custom views. A custom view contains an `ImageView` and a listener. Listener can transform, show a photo in ImageView and upload the photo.

I want to take a photo from camera, return it to the fragment, pass to a view through listener (then show and upload inside the view). Everything works right until the activity is destroyed after camera becomes visible. So, after returning from camera, I restore the fragment, get photo in `onActivityResult` and try to pass to a view by listener. But a listener is `null`, and i don't know what view it is attached to.

How can I pass a photo to a view after recreating an activity?

Listener:

```
public interface Listener {
    void onPhotoObtained(@Nullable Uri uri);
}
```

Custom view:

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout implements Listener {
    @BindView(R.id.imageview) ImageView image;

    private PhotoManager photoManager;

    public void setPhotoManager(@NonNull PhotoManager photoManager) {
        this.photoManager = photoManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPhotoObtained(@Nullable Uri uri) {
        // transform and show image
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.imageview)
    void onPhotoButtonClicked() {
        photoManager.requestPhoto(this);
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements PhotoManager {

    @BindView(R.id.view1) CustomView view1;
    @BindView(R.id.view2) CustomView view2;

    // A list of listeners to communicate with custom views.
    // When a user clicks an ImageView, this fragment starts a camera to obtain a photo.
    private SparseArray<Listener> listeners;
    private int lastRequestId;
    private Uri uri;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        binder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        listeners = new SparseArray<>();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            lastRequestId = 0;
            uri = null;
        } else {
            lastRequestId = savedInstanceState.getInt(BUNDLE_REQUEST_ID);
            uri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BUNDLE_KEY_URI);
            // How to create a listener list?
        }

        view1.setPhotoManager(this);
        view2.setPhotoManager(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ReceivingPhotoDialogFragment.CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (uri != null) {
                    // listeners become empty after fragment reinitialization
                    Listener listener = listeners.get(lastRequestId);
                    if (listener != null)
                        listener.onPhotoObtained(uri);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        bundle.putInt(BUNDLE_REQUEST_ID, lastRequestId);
        bundle.putParcelable(BUNDLE_KEY_URI, uri);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void requestPhoto(@NonNull Listener listener) {
        listeners.put(++lastRequestId, listener);

        // Request new photo with lastRequestId
        showCamera(lastRequestId);
    }

    private void showCamera(int requestId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File file = null;
            try {
                file = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            uri = null;
            if (file != null) {
                uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                intent.putExtra(BUNDLE_REQUEST_ID, requestId);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File storageDir = getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(timeStamp, ".jpg", storageDir);
    }
}
```

A second listener to initialize first:

```
public interface PhotoManager {
    void requestPhoto(@NonNull Listener listener);
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code here for more understandings

Comment: Please post the logcat error message and the code.

Comment: @VishalChhodwani, ready.

Comment: @CoolMind You are testing it on Samsung device...?

Comment: @VishalChhodwani, not only (also on emulator running Android 4.4). In developer options I set a checkbox "Don't keep activities".

Answer (score 0):

I still struggle with the activity lifecycle, so this may not be the best answer.

What I do is make my listener as a static variable. This allows the variable to exist in the class instead of the instance of the class which clears when destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, You do not need to re-initialise listener for that,
What you need is add a property named `configChanges` in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file for that activity which has this **MainFragment**

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Add these tag `configChanges` and then run your code.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to have an application that will retain it's state after configuration change.